# How to get index of dictionary from an array of dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries:

```
var array = [["txt":"5mbps", "value": 2048],["txt":"50mbps", "value": 18048],["txt":"55mbps", "value": 22048]]
```

here, I want to get the *value* from that index of dictionaries, which *txt* is being selected. If I select 50mbps, how can i get that index and display the *value* of the same index .
- Swift

Comment: "that index of dictionaries" what do you mean by "index"? Give us a test input/output.

Comment: Maybe better use array of tuples? [(txt: String, value: Int)]

Comment: can you suggest me one example @Adrian

Comment: the keys mentioned in the dictionary has a name 'value', which is confusing :( @ale

Comment: sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe better use array of tuples

```
var array: [(txt: String, value: Int)] = [
    ("5mbps", 2048),
    ("50mbps", 18048),
    ("55mbps", 22048)
]
```

Swift 2.3

```
array.filter { element in
    return element.txt == findingText
}.first?.value
```

Swift 3

```
array.first { element in
    return element.txt == findingText
}?.value
```

Comment: `array.first { $0["txt"] as? String == "50mbps" }?["value"]`. A bit shorter :p

Comment: @Eendje Yes i know :), but i don't like write all in one line. I prefer use enther

Comment: okay, but can we perform this task if the 'key' text is unknown?

Comment: error:It says Use of unresolved identifier 'findingText'

Comment: oh, I got it. sorry @Ad

Comment: I will test it again @AdrianBobrowski

Comment: @Aashish findingText is the text you are looking for

Answer (score 16):

to get the index you can use:

```
let index = array.index(where: {$0["txt"] as! String == "5mbps"})
```

or to get the direct value

```
array.filter({$0["txt"] as! String == "5mbps"}).first
```

Comment: okay, but can we perform this task if the 'key' text is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

use filter

```
func searchValue(txt: String) -> Int? {

    if let f = (array.filter { $0["txt"] == txt }).first, value = f["value"] as? Int {
        return value
    }
    return nil
}

searchValue("5mbps") // 2048
searchValue("50mbps") // 18048
searchValue("55mbps") // 22048
```

Comment: okay, but can we perform this task if the 'key' text is unknown?

Comment: do you mean "txt" could be something else?

Comment: how about making it a function like this?

Answer (score 1):

**Latest Swift**: `index(where:)` is *deprecated* you have to use `firstIndex(where:)` function instead.

```
let index = array.firstIndex(where: { ( $0["yourKey"] as? String == "compareWithValue" ) } )
```

Note that, this `index` will be optional so you can use it after proper check as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**If the case is** to directly get the value from a dictionary based on given index (without using the key of the dictionary "txt"):

```
let givenIndexForArray = 1

if let value = array[givenIndexForArray]["value"] {
    print(value) // 18048
}
```

**If the case is** to get the value(s) based on the dictionaries' keys, you might face *duplication*:

In case of **duplication**, you need to get an *array of values*:

```
let givenKey = "50mbps"

let valueArray = array.filter { // [Optional(18048)]
    // assuming that the key is ALWAYS "txt", or value will be an empty array
    $0["txt"] == givenKey
    }
    .map {
        // assuming that the value is ALWAYS "value", or value will be an empty array
        $0["value"]
}
```

So, let's say that your array looks like this ("50mbps" key is duplicated):

```
var array = [["txt":"5mbps", "value": 2048],["txt":"50mbps", "value": 18048],["txt":"50mbps", "value": 22048]]
```

By applying the code snippet above, output should be: *[Optional(18048), Optional(22048)]*.

Finally, **if the case is** to get just one value (or the first if there is a duplication) simply, get `.first` from the same `valueArray` array:

```
let first = valueArray.first // 18048
```

Comment: okay, but can we perform this task if the 'key' text is unknown?

Comment: could you give an example? if key is not "txt" the output should be nil

Comment: I'm using 'txt' as a picker value, but I need to request API with the 'value' of the same index as the txt, been selected.